# I need some help on sentence making. What should I say?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-choice, sentence-usage

I am not a native English speaker and sometimes I find making sentence difficult. So I'm asking for help.

I was trying to express like that, "somebody has picked up a guy on his arm to throw him up from a high window or place and I want to say like please throw him up from a little bit higher altitude" It's just an example and nothing else.

So, I need to know which one would be perfect? and please if you find any mistake just tell me so that I can learn it and move ahead.

Here are my sentences I thought about:

1. Please drop him up from as high altitude as you can
2. Please throw him up from as high altitude as you can
3. Please throw him from as much altitude as you can.
4. Please get him to the highest altitude as you can and drop him.

Comment: "Drop up" is incorrect and is never used. In English you can either "drop **down**" or "throw out [of a window]" or possibly "throw down". It is possible to say "throw up" and not mean vomiting. For example, in basketball you try to throw the ball up into the basket. One version of what you ask is "_Please throw him from the highest point  [window / roof] you can_". _Altitude_ is not used in this context, it is associated more with aircraft and mountains - height above sea level.

Comment: @PeterJennings Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend something like "Please throw him from as high as you can." This is because 'throw up' has the separate connotation of vomiting, and altitude seems a bit too wordy. Drop him up seems like improper grammar, but I'm not sure of the rules regarding it. All in all, #3 seems like the best answer, but something still feels a bit off. Sorry I can't be definite, hope this helps!